# Prove that three of the segments can be used as the sides of a triangle of nonzero area

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

A set S of line segments contains 10 segments, no two of the same length, and for each segment x ∈ S we have

1 ≤ length(x) ≤ 55

Prove that three of the segments can be used as the sides of a triangle of nonzero area.

Comment: Any thoughts?  As you mention number theory, are the lengths constrained to be integers?  Not sure it matters one way or the other, but the $55$ suggests that the pigeon hole principle will be involved.

Comment: As a hint:  try to write out a "bad" collection.  Start with $1$ and then from there add in the smallest length that doesn't yield a triangle.  It's a familiar pattern.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is best tackled by "proof by contradiction". Suppose any three out of these 10 segments do not form a triangle of positive area. Arrange these 10 segments in the order of increasing length, $a_1,a_2,...,a_{10}$, with $a_1<a_2<...<a_{10}$. Then $a_1\ge1$, $a_2>1$. By our assumption,
$$a_3\ge a_1+a_2>2$$
$$a_4\ge a_2+a_3>1+2=3$$
$$a_5\ge a_3+a_4>2+3=5$$
and so forth. Finally we get
$$a_{10}\ge a_8+a_9>1+1+2+3+5+8+13+21+34=55$$
which contradicts the condition
$$length(x)\le55$$